# Update progressView in UITableView based on indexpath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, uiprogressview

I am working on a audio player app that should allow the user to click on a button on the UITableViewCell in a UITableView to play a song, then they can see the progression of the song on the progress bar. I don't want to create an object for each cell, I think that would cause me to lose significant efficiency, so instead I am using the dequeueReusableCell() function to initialize the cells based on data from excel.

For some reason, when I call my function updateProgress(), which should update the progressView value equal to the cell's AudioPlayer's current time, I get the error:

`*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:usingPresentationValues:]`

A timer is used to run updateProgres() every .5 seconds, which is my way of checking if the `btnPressed` bool is true of false (maybe there is a better way of doing this?). The only functions I am using to handle the whole process are segueBtn(), which is in my TableViewCell.swift class, updateProgress(), which is in my TableView.swift class, and viewDidLoad() in my ViewController.swift class. Here are those functions:

ViewController.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    parseCSV()
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(FirstViewController.updateProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateProgress() {
    if btnPressed == true {
        // Isolate Current Cell
        cell = tableView(myTableView, cellForRowAt: cellIndex) as! CustomTableViewCell
        if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            cell.progressView.setProgress(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime/audioPlayer.duration), animated: true)
        }
        else {
            cell.progressView.setProgress(Float(audioPlayer.currentTime), animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

TableViewCell.swift:

```
@IBAction func segueBtn(_ sender: Any) {
    do
    {
        cellIndex = (indexPath)!
        let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs[(indexPath?.row)!], ofType: ".mp3")
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

        // Indicates to updateProgress() that audio player is set up
        btnPressed = true
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    catch
    {
        print ("Audio Player was not set up correctly")
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can update the progressView of the correct cell using this strategy?

Comment: Are `cellIndex` and `btnPressed` global? Your player should probably not exist in the cell. You should have an array of players in your view controller. Your cells should just be the ui components; the progress view and the button. Use a delegation pattern to get the button tap back to the view controller and use your timer to update the progress bars of the visible cells.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you, adding the delegation pattern fixed the issue!